# Do I buy a travel adapter or can I simply replace the plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm in Singapore and I just bought a dryer. It came with this plug. it's listed as a BS 546/A plug
[image]

my wall socket fits this plug
[image]

can I simply switch the plug or do I have to buy a travel adapter? I'm not very good with electricity and stuff and I don't want to run the risk of blowing up my dryer!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What kind of dryer is it; hair dryer or clothes? You bought the dryer in the same country as you'll be using it, and the socket didn't fit? What's the make and model? (Edit the answers into your question.)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not very good with electricity and stuff

Put down the screw driver and step away from the appliance.

Yes, you should just buy an adapter.

Comment: The top plug is 15 amps, the bottom ones 13. It is worth checking the rating plate on the appliance